# Android SlideExpandableListView Remove Item

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am using the library found at:
https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

to provide slidedown views on my listitems.  The problem I am running into is that each of my list items has a delete button which will remove the item from the underlying adapter. When this happens if the item that was removed was expanded then the item below it will become expanded.  After digging through the source for the expandablelistview library I found that the culprit is a BitSet which is being used to keep track of the states of the listviews ( expanded 1, not expanded 0 ).  When I remove an item from the list the list of states does not get updated.  It needs to shift all values down.  The problem is I am not sure how to notify the library that my adapter has had an item removed from it.

My custom list adapter extends array adapter and when I remove an item I call notifyDataSetChanged.  Somehow I need to detect that call in the slideExpandablelistview which wraps my adapter so that I can update the BitSet.  IF anyone has worked with this library before or care to take a look I would love some help.

I create the expanandablelistview by doing

```
myAdapter= new SlideExpandableListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), new  ArrayList<CustomObject>()), R.id.contact_row, R.id.expandable);
```

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to get it to work?  If not, any alternative suggestions?

Comment: I think you just have to call `((ActionSlideExpandableListView) list).collapse();`  I've added an example below.

Answer (score 0):

"When this happens if the item that was removed was expanded then the item below it will become expanded."

After deleting the item from your ArrayList and then doing adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), you can do something like:

```
((ActionSlideExpandableListView) list).collapse();
```

Here is a full example that I made by modifying the author's sample that comes with the library:

```
package com.tjerkw.slideexpandable.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tjerkw.slideexpandable.library.ActionSlideExpandableListView;


public class ExampleActivity extends Activity 
{
    PersonDB db;
    ArrayList<String> people;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedData) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedData);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_expandable_list);

        final ActionSlideExpandableListView list = (ActionSlideExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list); 

        db = PersonDB.getInstance();
        people = db.getPeople();        

        adapter = new PersonArrayAdapter(people);

        list.setAdapter(adapter); 

        // listen for events in the two buttons for every list item.
        // the 'position' var will tell which list item is clicked
        list.setItemActionListener(new ActionSlideExpandableListView.OnActionClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View listView, View buttonview, int position)  
            { 
                switch (buttonview.getId())
                {
                case R.id.buttonA:

                    people.remove(position);
                    ((ArrayAdapter<String>) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ((ActionSlideExpandableListView) list).collapse();
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonB:

                    Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "You pressed buttonB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        // note that we also add 1 or more ids to the setItemActionListener
        // this is needed in order for the listview to discover the buttons
        }, R.id.buttonA, R.id.buttonB);

    }


    private class PersonArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
    {

        public PersonArrayAdapter(ArrayList<String> people) 
        {
            super(ExampleActivity.this, R.layout.expandable_list_item, people);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            // if we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_item, null);
            }

            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textView.setText(people.get(position)); 

            return convertView;
        }    

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return people.size(); 
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the dummy database class:

```
package com.tjerkw.slideexpandable.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PersonDB 
{

    private static PersonDB db = null;

    private ArrayList<String> people;


    private PersonDB()
    {
        people = new ArrayList<String>();

        // fill "database" with dummy data
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            people.add(i, "Person " + i);
    }


    public static PersonDB getInstance()
    {
        if (db == null)
            db = new PersonDB();

        return db;
    }


    public ArrayList<String> getPeople()
    {
        return people;
    }


    public String getPerson(int i)
    {
        return people.get(i);
    }


    public void deletePerson(int i)
    {
        people.remove(i);
    }

}
```

EDIT: I noticed a bug with this code.  When a row is deleted and the row below it moves up to fill that space, the text on the new row's buttonA appears left-justified.  The only way I could think of to solve this was to replace this line:

```
((ArrayAdapter<String>) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with these two lines:

```
adapter = new PersonArrayAdapter(people);                   
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If anyone has a better solution I would love to see it.